# How do I write the resolvent $R_{x}$ of $\rho K$ in terms of the $\rho$-resolvent $R$ of $K$?

Tags: real-analysis, integration, functional-analysis, measure-theory, partial-differential-equations

For $K,R\in L^{1}_{\text{loc}}(\mathbb R_{+})$ and $\rho>0$, assume that for $\rho>0$
$$R-K=\rho(K*R),$$

where $*$ represents convolution on $L^{1}_{\text{loc}}(\mathbb R_{+})$.

For some constant constant $C$ we want to find the solution $x$ to the equation

$$x = \rho K*x+C.$$

From the variation of constants formula, we know that

$$ x(t) = C - C\int_{0}^{t}R_{x}(s)ds,$$

where $R_{x}$ is the resolvent for $\rho K$, i.e.

$ \rho K* R_{x}=R_{x}*\rho K=\rho K-R_{x}$

**Question**: How can I write $R_{x}$ in terms of $R$. In particular I want to show that
$$ x(t) = C \int_{0}^{t}R(s)ds,$$

so there must be the following relation:

$$ 1-\int_{0}^{t}R_{x}(s)ds=\int_{0}^{t}R(s)ds$$

**My attempt**: $R_{x}(s)=e^{-\rho s}R(s)$ but it does not get me anywhere with partial integration.

I may be missing something very trivial here.

**EDIT**: By convolution in $L_{\text{loc}}^{1}(\mathbb R_{+})$, I mean for $t \geq 0$,

$$ (f*g)(t)=\int_{0}^{t}f(t-s)g(s)ds,$$

where $ f,g \in L_{\text{loc}}^{1}(\mathbb R_{+})$.

Comment: What is the "convolution in $L^1_{\mathrm{loc}}(\mathbb R_+)$"? Can you write it explicitly?

Comment: @GiuseppeNegro I have edited my initial post to also explain the convolution I mean.

Comment: You have typos somewhere, either $\rho K * R_x = \rho K + R_x$ or you have $x= c + c\int_0^t R_x$ with $\rho K * R_x = R_x - \rho K$, otherwise $x=c+c\int_0^t R_x$ is not a solution. Next the equation $1- \int_0^t R_x = \int_0^t R$ is impossible, the right-hand side is $0$ at $t=0$ while the left-hand side is $1$.